# Why isn't my multichannel mapping working correctly?

Tags: ios, swift, avaudioplayer, avaudiosession, avaudioengine

I recently posted this question about using multiroute with iOS and I thought I solved it, however I've discovered is doesn't quite work: [AVAudioEngine Multichannel mapping](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62078835/avaudioengine-multichannel-mapping)

The issue I'm having is the multiroute is only working for the first two output channels. I'm trying to make it work for a 4 channel audio interface.

I have managed to route audio to each output of the USB interface using AVAudioPlayer:

```
var avplayer = AVAudioPlayer()

@IBAction func avAudioPlayerPlay(_ sender: Any)
{
    let audioSession = AVAudioSession.sharedInstance()
    let route = audioSession.currentRoute

    // set the session category
    do
    {
        //try audioSession.setCategory(.multiRoute)
        try audioSession.setCategory(.multiRoute, options: .mixWithOthers)
    }
    catch
    {
        print("unable to set category", error)
        return
    }

    // activate the audio session - turns on multiroute I believe
    do
    {
        try audioSession.setActive(true)
        //try audioSession.setActive(true, options: .notifyOthersOnDeactivation)
    }
    catch
    {
        print("unable to set active", error)
        return
    }

    //audio interface + headphone jack
    let outputs:[AVAudioSessionChannelDescription] = [
        route.outputs[0].channels![2], // 3rd channel on Audio Interface
        route.outputs[1].channels![1]  // Right Channel of Headphones
    ]

    guard let filePath: String = Bundle.main.path(forResource: "audio", ofType: "m4a") else { return }
    let fileURL: URL = URL(fileURLWithPath: filePath)

    do
    {
        avplayer = try AVAudioPlayer(contentsOf: fileURL)
    }
    catch
    {
        print("play error", error)
        return
    }

    avplayer.channelAssignments = outputs

    let result = avplayer.play()
    print(result)
}
```

But I can't get it to work using AVAudioEngine:

```
private func getOutputChannelMapIndices(_ names:[String?]) -> [Int]
{
    let session = AVAudioSession.sharedInstance()
    let route = session.currentRoute
    let outputPorts = route.outputs

    var channelMapIndices:[Int] = []

    for name in names
    {
        var chIndex = 0
        for outputPort in outputPorts
        {
            guard let channels = outputPort.channels else
            {
                continue
            }
            for channel in channels
            {
                print(channel.channelName)
                if channel.channelName == name
                {
                    if names.count > channelMapIndices.count
                    {
                        channelMapIndices.append(chIndex)
                    }
                }
                chIndex += 1
            }
        }
    }
    return channelMapIndices
}

@IBAction func nodesPlay(_ sender: Any)
{
    let channelNames = [
        "UMC204HD 192k 3",
        "Headphones Left",
        "Headphones Right",
        nil
    ]

    let audioSession = AVAudioSession.sharedInstance()

    // set the session category
    do
    {
        //try audioSession.setCategory(.multiRoute)
        try audioSession.setCategory(.multiRoute, options: .mixWithOthers)
    }
    catch
    {
        print("unable to set category", error)
        return
    }

    // activate the audio session - turns on multiroute I believe
    do
    {
        try audioSession.setActive(true)
        //try audioSession.setActive(true, options: .notifyOthersOnDeactivation)
    }
    catch
    {
        print("unable to set active", error)
        return
    }

    let channelMapIndices = getOutputChannelMapIndices(channelNames)

    print("channelMapIndices: ", channelMapIndices)

    engine = AVAudioEngine()
    output = engine.outputNode
    mixer = engine.mainMixerNode

    player = AVAudioPlayerNode()

    engine.attach(player)

    guard let filePath: String = Bundle.main.path(forResource: "audio", ofType: "m4a") else { return }
    let fileURL: URL = URL(fileURLWithPath: filePath)
    let file = try! AVAudioFile(forReading: fileURL)

    let outputNumChannels = output.outputFormat(forBus: 0).channelCount
    print("outputNumChannels:" , outputNumChannels)

    var outputChannelMap:[Int] = Array(repeating: -1, count: Int(outputNumChannels))

    let numberOfSourceChannels = file.processingFormat.channelCount
    print("numberOfSourceChannels: ", numberOfSourceChannels)

    var sourceChIndex = 0
    for chIndex in channelMapIndices
    {
        if chIndex < outputNumChannels && sourceChIndex < numberOfSourceChannels
        {
            outputChannelMap[chIndex] = sourceChIndex
            sourceChIndex += 1
        }
    }

    print("outputChannelMap: ", outputChannelMap)

    if let au = output.audioUnit
    {
        let propSize = UInt32(MemoryLayout.size(ofValue: outputChannelMap))
        print("propSize:", propSize)
        let result = AudioUnitSetProperty(au, kAudioOutputUnitProperty_ChannelMap, kAudioUnitScope_Global, 0, &outputChannelMap, propSize)
        print("result: ", result)
    }

    let channelLayout = AVAudioChannelLayout(layoutTag: kAudioChannelLayoutTag_DiscreteInOrder | UInt32(numberOfSourceChannels))
    let format = AVAudioFormat(streamDescription: file.processingFormat.streamDescription, channelLayout: channelLayout)

    engine.connect(player, to: mixer, format:format)
    engine.connect(mixer, to: output, format:format)

    player.scheduleFile(file, at: nil, completionHandler: nil)

    do
    {
        try engine.start()
    }
    catch
    {
        print("can't start", error)
        return
    }

    player.play()
}
```

If anyone could explain why I can't seem to play any audio to output 3 or 4 I would really appreciate it.

Note, a lot of this code was translated from here: https://forums.developer.apple.com/thread/15416

Comment: What is the value of `kAudioOutputUnitProperty_ChannelMap` before you set it? How many channels are in `kAudioUnitProperty_StreamFormat` on the output unit?

Comment: kAudioOutputUnitProperty_ChannelMap appears to be blank before I set it. If I get it after I set it then it appears that only the first value of the array is set. There appears to be 4 channels on the output.

Comment: I’ve discovered if I multiply propSize by 4 then getting the channelmap returns the correct result... but the output still isn’t correct

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I believe the problem is the line

```
let propSize = UInt32(MemoryLayout.size(ofValue: outputChannelMap))
```

This is giving you the size of the array object, which is essentially the size of a pointer, not the size of the objects in the array. See [the discussion in the Apple docs](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/memorylayout/2432227-size).

The size of the property should be the number of channels contained in the array multiplied by the size of `Int32`, since `AudioUnitSetProperty` is a C API and that would be the size of a corresponding C array.

```
let propSize = UInt32(MemoryLayout<Int32>.stride * outputChannelMap.count)
```

You should also declare `outputChannelMap` as an array of `Int32` since that is the type expected by `kAudioOutputUnitProperty_ChannelMap`:

```
var outputChannelMap:[Int32] = Array(repeating: -1, count: Int(outputNumChannels))
```

Comment: Yep. This is the output: 0: -1, 1: -1. If I multiply propSize by two I get this: 0: -1, 1: -1, 2: -1, 3: -1.

Comment: Also.. this is what outputChannelMap looks like: [-1, -1, 0, -1]

Comment: If I don't multiply by two I only get two array values.

Comment: I think you may have pointed me in the right direction.. I've just changed outputChannelMap to an array of Int32 values and its outputing the correct mapping now

Comment: I've just tried it with a second usb interface and this seems to work for the propSize: let propSize:UInt32 = UInt32(MemoryLayout.size(ofValue: outputChannelMap)) * (outputNumChannels / numberOfSourceChannels) - Does this make any sense?

Comment: I meant the propSize for setting the output map. Sorry about the confusion. I've changed it now to this which I think is actually correct: `let propSize:UInt32 = UInt32(MemoryLayout<Int32>.stride * outputChannelMap.count)`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/215551/discussion-between-castles-and-sbooth).